# How to embed multiple view blocks into a view block and display them conditionally?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I'm trying to embed multiple view blocks into a single view block. However, I want each of the other views displayed only if they meet certain conditions.

What is the best way to do this?

Im running Drupal 6 with Views 2 and CCK.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use multiple blocks and use the block visibility options to decide what is displayed.

Comment: The problem is I am using Quicktabs to display the content. Quicktabs only allows one view block per tab. So I somehow need to display everything in a single view.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer.

If you can't use multiple blocks and the standard block visiblility. The other way you can work around this is to use hook_block in your own module to call the views when needed. either by using views_block() or calling [views_embed_view()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/views_embed_view/6)